# How do I share Build Definitions across Projects in Visual Studio Team Services?

Tags: azure-devops, devops, azure-pipelines

I have created a build definition in one project on Visual Studio Team Services and now I want to be able to re-use that build definition across other projects. What is the best way of doing this? I had hoped this would be a little more intuitive, but I see no clear way of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

VSTS is not support to share build definitions between projects now. But you can use [Export/Import Build Definition extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=onlyutkarsh.ExportImportBuildDefinition) to achieve it.

Also, there is [an user voice here](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/8468566-vso-build-vnext-share-build-templates-between-pro), you can vote and follow up.

Answer (score 1):

there is now an export feature which you can access by clicking the 3 elipsis from the build definition list.

It exports a JSON file which can be imported into a different subscription.